# ORM has schema to generate classes, does the reverse exist?

Tags: database, orm

In Entity-Framework, you can create a DB schema, and then generate your ORM classes.  Is there any software that does this in reverse?  For example you create a few classes that have relationships, and software generates a database schema with the relevant primary and foreign key relationships?

Comment: use code-first approach starting from EF4.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is available in EF starting from version EF 4.1.

You can do it with Entity Framework, using [Code First](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/).

EF 4.3 even has [Migrations built-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough).

Comment: Migrations are already available in EF 4.3. One of the new EF5 features shown in the video are spatial datatypes and spatial searches.

Comment: @KristofClaes: Thanks. Didn't realise that.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with DataNucleus/JDO, with Derby as the underlying database engine. It works, but you have to be *ever* so careful when doing it because effectively your *classes are the schema* and need to be subject to the usual level of carefulness with schema management.

I'm not sure I'd do it the same way again if I was starting out afresh.